# How to convert ECG Data to Graphical Data so that it can be used in GNNs?

Tags: neural-network, graph-neural-network

I am trying to predict arrythmia using GCNN but the problem i am facing is that the data is in tabular format *screenshot attached below*. Upon reading i found out that there needs to nodes and edges for it to work on GCNN. So, how can i convert into the graph data?[image]